# Verilog: proper way of connecting ports

Tags: verilog, hdl

Assume there are two different modules (`first_module`, `second_module`). Both of the modules are synchronized with clock signal. `first_module` has the following structure:

```
module first_module(
input clk,
input reset_n,
input in1,
output reg out1,
output reg out2
);

//******** some verilog codes *********

endmodule
```

And `second_module` has similar structure:

```
module second_module(
input clk,
input reset_n,
input in1,
input in2,
output reg out1
);

//******** some verilog codes *********

endmodule
```

And then there is a module called `top_module` which uses instances of both modules:

```
module top_module(
input clk,
input reset_n,
input insignal1,
input insignal2,
output outsignal1,
output outsignal2
);

first_module fm1(
  .clk(clk),
  .reset_n(reset_n),
  .in1(insignal1),
  .out1(outsignal1),
  .out2(<connection1>) // to be connected to the connection2 
);

second_module sm1(
  .clk(clk),
  .reset_n(reset_n),
  .in1(insignal2),
  .in2(<connection2>), // to be connected to the connection1
  .out1(outsignal2)
);    

endmodule
```

The aim is to connect `connection1` to `connection2`. According to my knowledge (if it is correct), we can either declare a single wire (let its name be `connection`) and replace both `<connection1>` and `<connection2>` with it, or we can declare two distinct wires `connection1` and `connection2`, then:

```
assign connection2 = connection1;
```

And connect them accordingly.

- **Are those two methods synthesized differently?** If the answer is yes, I would be glad if you could explain how they are synthesized.
- **If the answer is no, can one of the methods be better than the other in different conditions?** Not in terms of lines of code or simplicity, but in terms of synthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a difference. But not in your specific case.

Using a connection directly makes that is can be uni-directional or bi-directional depending on what the underlying ports in the module are.

But `assign connection2 = connection1;` is only uni-directional.

Thus between bi-directional ports should use direct connections or you should only use bi-directional Verilog constructs between them. The `assign ...` is not one of them.

But in you case the signal is uni-directional so it does not matter.

Note that modern FPGAs no longer have on-chip bi-directional buses. (At least I don't know one that has). Also in chip design on-chip buses are strongly discourage or outright forbidden by the manufacturers.
Therefore bi-directional signals are normally only present in the test-bench. As that does not get synthesized your question does not apply there.

Last but not least:
In HDL design I would strongly discourage from changing the name of a signal for no apparent reason. Having the same name throughout the design makes it easier to debug and trace your signals post-synthesis.